# how do i add a value to autonumber in access?

Tags: microsoft-access-2007

i was given a task to create a customers table with the 'customerID' starting from 100 and increment by 1. in the table is a field called 'nationality', is there a way to auto add the customer's country code to the 'customerID', giving  something like "44100, 233101, ..."?

Answer (score 0):

You should generate this numbery in a query.

```
NewID: [Countrycode]&[customerID]
```

Comment: could you please explain further?